# As vs what in this sentence

Tags: word-difference

My textbook only considers the sentence with "what" to be correct, but I can't see why "as" doesn't work.

> But car ownership is not as it was.
>   But car ownership is not what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbook is correct, *what* is correct.

Definition of *as*:

> used in comparisons to refer to the extent or degree of something

Here it is not being used as a comparison.

You could compare it to something making it a simile in the same sentence:

> But car ownership is not **as popular as it was**

Comment: I wonder! According to this rule, it is incorrect to write: **Things are not as they used to be** but it would be correct to write **things are not as good as they used to be**.